# The filteredProducts does not seems to be working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to identify the error in the code. I tried to make the filtered product work so the filtered product is does not seems to work. Is there an error in my code?

The getProduct function is working very well but when I use the second useEffect it does not seems to cause any change in the filteredproduct.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import styled from "styled-components";
import {popular} from "../data";
import Product from "./Product";


const Container = styled.div`
   padding: 20px;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
   justify-content: space-between;
`;

const Products = (cat,filters,sort) => {
   const[products,setProducts]= useState([]);
   const[filteredProducts,setFilteredProducts]= useState([]);

   useEffect(()=> {
      const getProduct = async()=>{
         try{
            const res = await axios.get(cat ?   `http://localhost:5000/api/products?categories=${cat}`:  "http://localhost:5000/api/products");
           setProducts(res.data);
         }catch(err){

         }
      };
      getProduct();
   },[cat]);

   useEffect(()=>{
         cat && 
         setFilteredProducts(
         products.filter((item)=>
         Object.entries(filters).every(([key,value])=>
         item[key].includes(value)
         )
         )
      );
   },[products,cat,filters]);
   console.log(filteredProducts);
    return (
      <Container>
         {filteredProducts.map((item)=>(
            <Product item = {item} key = {item.id}/>
         ))}
      </Container>
    );
  };
     
  
  export default Products;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what your problem is.
But there is some problem in your code.
In the first `useEffect` You don't need to put `cat` in the dependencies. Because it's not changeable in the code just keep it empty.

```js
useEffect(() => {} , [])
```

When you change it from the parent. The whole component will rerender.

Secondly, In the second `useEffect` You passed `products` arry as dependency. This is bad.

When rerender component React will compare the old version of dependencies and the newest. If they aren't the same It run the callback function in useEffect.

But Javascript save array and object by thier memory referance (e.x: 000x5) not their value (e.x: [1, 2, 3]).

```js
[] === [] // false
[1] === [] // false
{} === {} // false
```

So when React render `Products` component for the first time. It will run the useEffect callback and save dependencies refered which was (000x5). Then rerender the whole component and make new `products` array with different referance (000x6). When It compare the new useEffect dependencies with the old. The arry will be differnt. (000x5 !== 000x6) So It will run the useEffect callback again and again forever. This is will infinte loop and the app will broke and log an error to console saying `too many re-renders... bla bla bla`

So you have to pass a vaild dependency. Like `products.length` it will be number. or any vaild dependency like string, number and boolean.

**OR** when you update `products` value use `useCallback` hook.

And also You don't need to put cat and filters in the second useEffect deps. They are not changable. Morever If filters is array or object.

I hope if this helps you. If not please tell more details about the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have tried what you suggested but it didnt work. my problem is that i tried to select items from a data of products (category).the selected items will feature as filtered product . but the useeffect for the filteredproduct  does not seems to work even when i remove cat as the the dependency as you suggested.